# how can i reset form in react rsuite library?

Tags: reactjs, forms

So I am using `r-suite react library` and I have problem on form reset

When I use use-Ref hook to reset form it gave me error that `form-Ref.current.reset()` is not function

I also try `form-ref.current = null` but it does not work form some reason

so how can I reset my form ?

I have problem on reset form and its look like that r-suite react library can not let me reset the form

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import {
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  Button,
  Container,
  FlexboxGrid,
} from "rsuite";
import { quotationModel } from "../validation/validation";

const AddFormjsx = ({ addQuotation }) => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(undefined);

  const formRef = useRef();

  const handleVal = (e) => setVal(e);

  const handleSubmite = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    if (e) {
      formRef.current.reset();
      addQuotation(val);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container style={{ marginTop: "2rem" }}>
      <FlexboxGrid justify="center">
        <Form
          layout="inline"
          model={quotationModel}
          onChange={handleVal}
          onSubmit={handleSubmite}
          ef={formRef}
        >
          <FormGroup>
            <FormControl
              name="itemName"
              placeholder="Item name"
              style={{ width: 160 }}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <FormControl
              name="itemPrice"
              placeholder="Item price"
              style={{ width: 160 }}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <FormControl
              name="itemQuontity"
              placeholder="Item Quontity"
              style={{ width: 160 }}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <Button type="submite">Add</Button>
        </Form>
      </FlexboxGrid>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default AddFormjsx;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on this line: `ef={formRef}` but should be `ref={formRef}`

Replace: `formRef.current.reset();` to `formRef.current._reactInternals.child.stateNode.reset()` and also add `formRef.current.state.formValue = null`  for intenal value reset if u using it with model verification if not it will skip it

Comment: btw it aso not the problem it always give me error like this ` formRef.current.reset is not a function`

Comment: the "Form" component has no prop "ef".  What returns console.log(formRef.current) ?

Comment: here is the image link of it : https://postimg.cc/q6zxCF37

Comment: `const handleSubmite = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    if (e) {
      console.log(formRef.current);
      formRef.current.reset();
      addQuotation(val);
    }
  };`
what will output `console.log(formRef.current)`

Comment: here is the console.log of useRef : https://postimg.cc/75xM3b7c and about console.log of e it retun tru the thing is this library havily modify thing so i cant get around with it

Comment: i really appreciate your answer but it actually solve half problem to reset shown value but the internal value are still set so im using  " formRef.current.state.formValue = null " this to solve that problem and i also look into it and the reason that dont work in first place is becuse the form itset nested under div with seprate inpute i really dont know why they did it but yhe thnks for you reply and you affort and also happy coding